# SoftException in Application.cpp: Could not execute script

Tags: php, apache, magento, exception

Errors suddenly occur when I open magento site; every page is blank. There is no error generated in mageto error log file, but in php error log I have found the following:

> SoftException in Application.cpp:641: Could not execute script "/home/public_html/index.php" client denied by server configuration: /home/public_html/app/etc/local.xml

I searched the web, and applied solutions I found, but have had no success.

I give appropriate file permissions to both files which gives error.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your {{base_url}} and {{secure_base_url}} with white space problem.

might be some times when we are adding url to both. it may be at the end of the string will take "\n"

Comment: I have check this issue, but there is no white space btw thanks for reading my question and your time

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to update the ownership of the folders to the user account
Mainly the following 2:

```
chown -R user:group /home/user/public_html
chown user:nobody /home/user/public_html
```